# Android listview item deletion changes its position

Tags: android, listview, dialog

Hello I am working with android list view . I have a custom list view and I am looking to delete on long click of list view item. I used base adapter to set array list data in list view. Now the problem is that when I am looking to delete an item in the list view another item get deleted.How can I solve this.Please help me thanks in advance :)

```
 l1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewList.this);

                ListView modeList = new ListView(ViewList.this);
                String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Edit", "Delete" };
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
                modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

                builder.setView(modeList);
                final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

                modeList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,final int position,long id) {


                        switch (position) {
                        case 0:Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "edit", 5000).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();break;
                        case 1: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delete", 5000).show();


                        new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewList.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "deleted", 5000).show();

                                date_array.remove(position);
                                day_array.remove(position); 
                                month_array.remove(position);
                                sent_array.remove(position);

                                 l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(month_array,date_array,day_array,sent_array));
                            }
                         })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancelled", 5000).show();
                            }
                         })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                         .show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;

                        default: System.out.println("Sunday");break;
                    }

                    }
                });


                 dialog.show();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long clicked at"+pos, 5000).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

**Update** I can't delete the top most item.When I delete another item, the item just below the topmost item get deleted

Comment: Use **pos** in place of **position** in your code. Also you should use **notifyDataSetChanged()** instead of setting adapter again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**position** is the position of your "delete" button, so is always 1, which would correspond to the second item in your arrays. **pos** is the index for which you want to delete.